# R compare all elements of list amongst themselves

Tags: r, list, compare

Imagine you have a named list of vectors where the names are people and the vectors are the fruits they like.

```
fruits <- list("john" = c("apples", "oranges", "peaches", "kiwis"),
               "casey" = c("apples", "grapes", "grapefruits"),
               "nick" = c("apples", "pinapples", "kiwis", "grapefruits"),
               "brandon" = c("apples"))
```

I would like to compare `fruits$john` to all other vectors in the list, and then `fruits$casey` to all other elements but without then again comparing it to `fruits$john`, and so on. I know you could do something like

```
for (i in 1:length(fruits)){
 for (j in 1:length(fruits)){
  if (j > i){
```

But I was hoping for an lapply based method so I could parallelize with mclapply. I have this but it's awful.

```
fruit.vec <- names(fruits)

names(fruit.vec) <- names(fruits)

lapply(fruit.vec, function(x){
  other.people <- fruit.vec[fruit.vec != x]

  lapply(other.people, function(y){
    intersect(fruits[[x]], fruits[[y]])
  })
})
```

It returns a list of lists of where the top level list is a person and each sublist is named for the comparison performed between said person and the others and is a vector of common fruits. The vector `fruit.vec` and naming (I believe) are necessary to preserve the names and make them come out as the list names in this case.

Comment: What is your expected output for given example?

Comment: Someone has to ask... "How can you compare apples with oranges?"

Comment: `unlist(combn(fruits,2,function(x)setNames(list(do.call(intersect,unname(x))),paste(names(x),collapse = "_")),simplify = FALSE),FALSE)`

Comment: The expected answer would be what Onyambu's code gives, that is, some result that indicates to me what is common between any two given elements of the list for all possible combinations, without repeats. Though Onyambu has solved this.